# How to pause a setInterval, wait for the execution of another function and resume the setInterval

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, asynchronous, setinterval

I'm trying to loop a function with a setInterval and then, when a condition is hitted:

1. Pause the setInterval loop
2. Call and execute an async function
3. Resume the setInterval loop

What's the best way to do it in Javascript?
I have something like this:

```
var refreshId = setInterval(Myfunction, 5);

function  Myfunction(){
---do something---

if (conditionIsHitted){
externalFunction();}
}
 ---resume the setInterval loop again
```

Comment: What kind of function will be executed? An asynchronous one or a synchronous one?

Comment: can you please edit your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Otherwise we have no idea what's actually going on in your code.

Comment: edited with a better explication

Answer (score -1):

you cant "pause" a setinterval. nor a setTimeout. but you can stop it and start it again later. like start with a 10 sec timeout. stop it 2 seconds later. and restart it later with a 8 sec timeout.

```
// run something after 10 sec - will never actually be runned, because stopped later
let timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('10 sec elapsed');
}, 10000);

// stop after 2 seconds and relaunch the work to be done
setTimeout(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('10 sec elapsed');
    }, 8000);
}, 2000);
```